# Where to get btrfs-convert on 18.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, btrfs

I installed `btrfs-progs` on 18.04, but `btrfs-convert` is still not available. I have checked that the `btrfs-progs` [deb package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/btrfs-progs/4.15.1-1build1) does not contain `btrfs-convert`, only its man page.

How can I get `btrfs-convert` on 18.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`btrfs-convert` was a part of "btrfs-tools" package, which in Bionic will be provided as "btrfs-progs".

However if you check the [list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/btrfs-progs/filelist) of "btrfs-progs" files, you would find out that the man page of `btrfs-convert` has been included but not the binary itself.

There is also a bug report: [btrfs-convert executable is not included in btrfs-progs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-progs/+bug/1774794)

Also it might be dropped because of: [btrfs-progs: please stop shipping btrfs-convert](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=854489)

You have to compile it from source I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I grabbed a copy from suse and used that  ( https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.0/opensuse-oss/btrfsprogs-4.15-lp150.1.2.x86_64.rpm.html ). (All my data's backed up so I'm not so concerned about the unreliability.

EDIT: as I was warned, I basically got a filesystem that didn't really work (Would go read-only just after booting)

Ran into this bug:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194667

I second the above advice, currently btrfs-convert doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Instead of btrfs-convert, you could try to use fstransform.

Like the other posters, btrfs-convert produced a broken filesystem for me while fstransform did the job. It says the support for btrfs is still untested, but you can run it with an according parameter to do it anyway.

Do not forget to back up data! As always.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a statically compiled version of a recent btrfs-progs that I found at https://wiki.tnonline.net/w/Btrfs/Statically_built_btrfs-progs, specifically: https://mirrors.tnonline.net/btrfs/btrfs-progs/x86_64/btrfs-progs-6.6.3-x86_64-static/.

Use software compiled by untrusted others at your own risk. Looks like these are automatically compiled by GitHub Actions at: https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs